# google sites html box tool css postion absolute

Tags: css-position, google-sites

I have a problem when I use Google sites to create my HTML. As I know, HTML Box tool can hold HTML Code and Javascripts. Therefore, I want create a float div covering my main page as most advertisements do. 
So I create code like below:

```
<div style="left:100px;top:100px;position:absolute; border:1px #EEEEEE solid;
            border-radius:20px;width:200px;height:200px">
    anything here.........
</div>
```

And if I set the position to absolute, My information will be hidden after the page is loaded.

Steps:

1. create a HTML Box when add a page in Google Site, sites.google.com
2. edit HTML Box and input codes I mentioned above
3. save and use IE to open the web sites
4. Firstly, you can see what you typed inside the div and the div will be gone

Is it a bug or feature of HTML Box of Google Site?

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear  what you're saying here. Could you clarify a bit more?

Comment: I modified, please check.